# Java Apache POI Excel set border on specific cell and set currency cell format

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am working to generate excel using java apache poi
i just need to beautify it (with border)

below is the excel that i have successfuly create
[image: excel]

and here is the excel that i wanted (see those border and currency and background color)
[image]

heres some of my code to generate the excel

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Product Name");
row.createCell(1).setCellValue("name");

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("excel.xlsx");
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: See if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930668/add-border-to-merged-cells-in-excel-apache-poi-java) can be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you'd need to break down the creation of your cell in this format first before applying any style onto it:

```
                    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
                    cell1.setCellValue("Product Name");
```

Later,

```
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setBorderTop((short) 1); // single line border
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        ...//add many others here
        cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyle); //apply that style to the cell
```

Simple way is to create a cellStyle at first and then just go ahead with numerous cell creations as per the application requirement! Next, just loop into each cell to apply the cellStyle if it is a common behavior that you need for all.
Hope that helps!

Comment: any idea for currency format? and background color? @robot_alien

Comment: for the color you can use `cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);` and for the currency format a hint: you'll need to use decimal formatter to format it. Please upvote if this answer helped you. Thanks!

Comment: so for currency i must change it from java? instead excel format?
i see, thank you